# What does less than 0. (0 dot) mean?

Tags: c

I just saw this for the first time. The source code I'm looking at is in C

```
 if( rate < 0.){
   ...
 }
 else{
   ...
 }
```

What happens if `rate=0` ?

Comment: it should be `0.0`  try `sizeof(0.)`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `0.` and `0.0` are the same thing

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes this is what I means `0.` is `0.0`.

Comment: 0 is not less than 0, so if rate = 0 it would result in false.

Comment: check this: http://codepad.org/GhfrQ9YO What I mean to say in first comment

Comment: If `rate = 0` then `rate` will be assigned the value of `0`. :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: The size of `0.` vs. `0.0` doesn't really make the relevant point, which is that `0.0`, `.0`, and `0.` are all valid syntax for a floating-point constant of type `double` with the value zero.

Comment: @KeithThompson Hmm got it! I was not aware of this that all three are valid syntax. Thanks!

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of two different questions. It's not a duplicate of the first one, "C++ difference between 0 and 0.0". It is a duplicate of the second, "C++ difference between 0. and 0.0".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`0.` is a literal of type `double` (and value zero). By contrast, `0` is a literal of type `int`.

Comment: BTW: `0` is an octal-constant. ;-)  Like _that_ makes any difference.(C11 6.4.4.1 1)

Comment: @chux: Well of course - who'd think anything else? :-)

Answer (score 6):

It is interpreting `0.` as a double (`0.0`) instead of an integer (`0`).

Check the link: of ["working code"](http://codepad.org/LdSzUu5Y), showing the different sizes of various types of zero constants:

Comment: It certainly isn't: if it's doing anything it's making it a double rather than an int.

Comment: Yes, @Phil is correct.  You need 0.0f to get a float value, double is the default.

Comment: Fixed.  (Thanks for noting that.)

Comment: @Jim add this link of [codepade](http://codepad.org/GhfrQ9YO)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan  good link, but should have sizeof(0) as well, no?

Comment: `foo = 1; if (foo == 1.0)…` works perfectly well; there is no floating-point error, and the test evaluates to true.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  I wasn't necessarily referring to that particular comparision, but comparing ints with floating-point in general.  Most of the time they are fine, but sometimes not.

Comment: @Jim remove that its confusing, and not needed

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan can you edit the codepad? I don't have an account there.

Comment: @Jim I have edited and updated link in your answer already check. I suggest you to post that link with a small explanation.

Comment: @StephenCanon  Fixed.  Removed cast reference.

Answer (score 2):

`0.` is a *floating constant* and since it does not have a suffix it is a `double`, from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.4.2` *Floating constants* we have the following grammar:

```
floating-constant:
   decimal-floating-constant
   hexadecimal-floating-constant
decimal-floating-constant:
   fractional-constant exponent-partopt floating-suffixopt
   digit-sequence exponent-part floating-suffixopt
[...]
fractional-constant:
    digit-sequenceopt . digit-sequence
    digit-sequence .                                   < ---- This covers 0.
[...]
```

We then have in paragraph *4*:

> **An unsuffixed floating constant has type double.** If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has
>   type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double.